# Reset an already subscribed stream with new parameters

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have following function which returns a stream to a Firestore collection of users which I can filter by age:

```
Stream<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> users({int age}) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .orderBy('age')
        .startAt([
          age
        ])
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList());
}
```

I am subscribing to that stream via a StreamSubscribtion in a stateful widget:

```
StreamSubscription _streamSubscription = DatabaseService.users(age: 25).listen((users) {
              print('users found: ' + users.length.toString());
});
```

Of course I cancel this subscription in the dispose function of that stateful widget.

**My Question is:**
How can I change the filter, the age? Do I have to unsubscribe first and then re-subscribe to the stream with the new age value? Or can I just change the age?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries are immutable. This means that you can't change the age value on the existing query, and will indeed have to create a new query.

Comment: Hi Frank. Nice to meet you. I've watched your presentation about querying Firestore based on geographic location. It was great! I'm from Germany btw :).
Regarding my question, let's take that geohash example: If I want to change the geohashes of my bounding box on a running stream, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Hey JustChris  You'll have to create new queries for the new conditions, and then have those replace the exiting queries. This can get quite involved, since you'll be managing all the state and deltas. For an example, see: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/packages/geofire/src/GeoQuery.ts#L230